# select nth file in folder (using sed)?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to select the nth file in a folder of which the filename matches a certain pattern:

Ive tried using this with sed: e.g., 
    sed -n 3p /path/to/files/*pattern*.txt

but it appears to return the 3rd line of the first matching file.

Ive also tried 
    sed -n 3p `ls /path/to/files/*pattern*.txt`
which doesnt work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why sed, when bash is so much better at it?

Assuming some name `n` indicates the index you want:

## Bash

```
files=(path/to/files/*pattern*.txt)
echo "${files[n]}"
```

## Posix sh

```
i=0
for file in path/to/files/*pattern*.txt; do
  if [ $i = $n ]; then
    break
  fi
  i=$((i++))
done
echo "$file"
```

What's wrong with `sed` is that you would have to jump through many hoops to make it safe for the entire set of possible characters that can occur in a filename, and even if that doesn't matter to you you end up with a double-layer of subshells to get the answer.

```
file=$(printf '%s\n' path/to/files/*pattern*.txt | sed -n "$n"p)
```

Please, [never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 /path/to/files/*pattern*.txt  | sed -n '3p'
```

or, if patterne is a regex pattern

```
ls -1 /path/to/files/ | egrep 'pattern' | sed -n '3p'
```

lot of other possibilities, it depend on performance or simplicity you look at